# URLReferer Vulnerability In Security Audit Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, security

I am checking `Request.UrlReferrer = null` on each `page_load` method outside of `Postback`. But if it's not null and still someone change the referrer header value using **BurpSuite**. Then it should redirect to default **errorpage**.

How should I validate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot trust user input, and request headers (including referer) are user input, they can be chosen arbitrarily by the client. Authorization decisions should not be based on this, because as you said, a client can send whatever referrer they want.

From your question it sounds more like you need some kind of a session to store client state.

Comment: Auditor has told to just redirect application to `ErrorPage` if anyone tamper the value of `referrer header`

Comment: You should ask them what they meant. You can redirect to an error page if the referrer is outside your domain (the referrer domain is not in a whitelist), but preventing tampering in general is not possible.

Comment: yes, but how should I check whether `referrer header` value has tampered or not?